# update column by specific old and new value in 1 column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHQ9q.jpg)

this is a log table all cards changed values saved in this table now i add column  to insert the old values for the the card the problem is i want to do in code is a procedure scan the table and but the old value in the new column.  what is old value the old value is the same value one the card is not duplicate then its have no old values but if it duplicate so there is an old value the image i upload Identifies what i want to do  thank you for help :)

Comment: Is there some field to order the records with? You only show a card_Code field, the existing total_number field, and the new total_number_o field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction to see how a previous value can be tracked (I am assuming a timestamp field called TS to track the order of instances for a given card_code. You will need to adjust to meet your data model). you just need to base an update around it, setting total_number_o for the given card_Code and TS.

```
with tab as ( 
          select 101012172583 card_code, '005' total_number, sysdate ts from dual
union all select 101012172583 card_code, '006' total_number, sysdate-1/12 ts  from dual
union all select 101012172583 card_code, '003' total_number, sysdate-2/12 ts  from dual
union all select 101012172583 card_code, '003' total_number, sysdate-3/12 ts  from dual
union all select 101012172583 card_code, '005' total_number, sysdate-4/12 ts  from dual
union all select 101012172583 card_code, '004' total_number, sysdate-5/12 ts  from dual
            )
select card_Code
     , total_number
     , lag(total_number) over ( partition by card_code order by ts) total_number_o
     , ts 
from tab order by card_Code, ts desc;     

CARD_CODE                              TOTAL_NUMBER   TOTAL_NUMBER_O   TS                     
101012172583                           "005"          "006"            01/12/2015 3:16:35 PM  
101012172583                           "006"          "003"            01/12/2015 1:16:35 PM  
101012172583                           "003"          "003"            01/12/2015 11:16:35 AM 
101012172583                           "003"          "005"            01/12/2015 9:16:35 AM  
101012172583                           "005"          "004"            01/12/2015 7:16:35 AM  
101012172583                           "004"                           01/12/2015 5:16:35 AM
```